# Is there anyway to convert string args to byte args in node js

Tags: javascript, node.js, hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, hyperledger-chaincode

I'm working on a project where I need to convert arguments that are in string array to byte array  arguments like shown below.

input:var = [arg1,arg2,arg3];//string array

output: array which consists of byte array format of each argument

I know a function in Go language called func ToChaincodeArgs(args ...string) [][]byte whic can do this conversion. Is there any other function similar to this in node js? If I need to convert manually without using any function then how can I do it?

Comment: What do you mean by "byte array format"?

Comment: Not sure why this is hyperledger related, this sounds like a standard "converting strings to byte arrays in Node" question? And yes, that's built in, but also has answers on SO and the wider web already.

Comment: See also [`buffer`](https://nodejs.org/api/buffer.html) and [`Uint8Array`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Uint8Array).

Answer (score 0):

Using the Hyperledger Fabric SDK for Node, you use strings as arguments to smart contract transaction functions so there is no need to convert them to byte arrays (or rather Buffer objects). For example:

```js
const result = await contract.submitTransaction('transactionName', 'arg1', 'arg2');
```

Or if you have an array of strings you want to use as arguments:

```js
const args = ['arg1', 'arg2'];
const result = await contract.submitTransaction('transactionName', ...args);
```